# How to initialize a constant map pointer to be empty in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

Simple question, I just want to initialize a map to be empty, instead of being a nullptr.

```
 const std::map<std::string, std::string>* emptyDictionary;
```

I tried

```
const std::map<std::string, std::string>* emptyDictionary = {"", ""};
```

but obviously that's not right.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Why involve pointers at all? Something as simple as `std::map<std::string, std::string> emptyDictionary;` (notice there are no pointers involved) does what you want.

Comment: i'm passing it to a function that requires it to be a pointer.

Comment: @unwiseguy: If the function accepts a pointer, simply take the address of your local object. No need to declare it as pointer as well.

Comment: or you can send the map by reference if the function signature can be changed.

Comment: @Philipp whether passing the address of a local to a function is a good idea absolutely depends on what the function is doing with it. What if it has side effects affecting the parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to make any map at all -- you just made a pointer! You can make the pointer point to a dynamically allocated map:

```
 const std::map<std::string, std::string>* emptyDictionary
     = new std::map<std::string, std::string>;
```

This map will be truly empty. If you add the initializer `{{"", ""}}`, which you may well do, then you don't actually have an empty map, but rather a map with one element which maps an empty string to an empty string.

Note that you can never modify your map through the const pointer, so it's a bit questionable why you'd want to do this.

Note also that wanton dynamic allocation is generally a poor programming style. There's almost surely a better way to do whatever you need to do, or, based on your comment, you're just grossly mis­under­stand­ing something: The best way to obtain a pointer is to take the **address of** an existing object:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
foo(&m); // pass address of m as a pointer
```

Comment: also no need to repeat the type names (for C++11, which it seems clear OP is using): `auto const *emptyDictionary = new std::map<std::string, std::string>;`

Comment: He uses the word 'nullptr' and his attempt at solving this problem involved an initializer_list/uniform initialization syntax.

Answer (score 3):

```
const std::map<std::string, std::string>* emptyDictionary 
     = new std::map<std::string, std::string>();
```

Comment: Since the OP apparently uses C++11, you can replace the first `std::map<…>*` type with `auto`.

Comment: While this will accomplish what the OP is asking, it would perhaps be a good idea to add "Do not ever do this" to the answer.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Maybe the function that is being called wants to take ownership of the object and `delete` it later. Not nice, but such things happen.

Comment: In that case, one should use `std::unique_ptr<std::map<std::string, std::string>> emptyDictionary(new std::map<std::string, std::string>());` and call `.release()` when calling the function.  (Or, one should rewrite the function to use automatic lifetime management techniques, though I agree this is not always possible.)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis constructing a unique_ptr and immeditately releasing it: all that just for clarity?

Answer (score 1):

The default (empty) constructor of map will create an empty map http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/.
Either declare the map with automatic allocation on the stack by just writing

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> emptyDictionary();
```

And send it to your function using the addres-off operator

```
yourfunction(&emptyDictionary);
```

However, if the dictionary will outlive the instance of it was created, you need to dynamically allocate it instead to avoid a call to its destructor.

```
const std::map<std::string, std::string>* emptyDictionary = new std::map<std::string, std::string>();
```

Then you dont need the address-of operator when calling your function.

```
yourfunction(emptyDictionary);
```

However, the responsibility of deallocation will then be yours. When you dont need the object any longer, you need to delete the object using the delete statement.

```
delete emptyDictionary;
```